# Can you still extract features from a digital signal without converting it to analog using MFCC?

Tags: signal-processing, feature-extraction, mfcc

I am developing a back-end speech recognition software wherein the user can import mp3 files. How can I extract the features from this digital audio file? should I convert it back to analog first?

Comment: Any chance to accept the answer so that question won't be floating around?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear, since you are using terms *analog* and *digital* incorrectly. Analog is a real-world, continuous function, i.e. voltage, pressure, etc. Digital is a discrete (sampled) and quantized version of the analog signal. You **must** calculate the FFT of your audio frames when calculating the MFCC's. You can extract MFCC's only from the digital signal - it's rather impossible to do it with the analog one.

If you are  asking about whether it is possible to extract the MFCC's from an mp3 file, then yes - it is possible. All you need is to perform the standard algorithm and you can get your features - obviously it is outside of spec of that question.

1. Calculate the FFT for frames of data.
2. Calculate the PSD by squaring the samples.
3. Apply the mel-filterbank and sum the energy across banks.
4. Calculate the logarithm of each of the energies.
5. Calculate the DCT of the logarithms of energies.

Comment: So does that mean I don't have to go through spectral analysis anymore? I'm new in this field and most sources I've found about MFCC process includes converting analog signal to digital signals.

Comment: I suggest you to read first some DSP fundamentals, chapter 1. You are using terms *analog* and *digital* incorrectly. Analog is a real-world, continuous function, i.e. voltage, pressure, etc. Digital is discretized (sampled) and quantized version of the analog signal. You **must** calculate the FFT of your audio frames when calculating the MFCC's.

Comment: The MFCC is short for mel frequency cepstrum coefficients and requires the FFT (or DFT).

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing things here, like @jojek said you can do all that WITH the digital signal. This here is a pretty spot on tutorial:

http://practicalcryptography.com/miscellaneous/machine-learning/guide-mel-frequency-cepstral-coefficients-mfccs/

This one is more practical:

http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/15-492/slides/03_mfcc.pdf

From Wikipedia: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum]

MFCCs are commonly derived as follows:[1][2]

- Take the Fourier transform of (a windowed excerpt of) a signal. Means short time fourier transform)
- Map the powers of the spectrum obtained above onto the mel scale, using triangular overlapping windows. (Calculation described in the links above)
- Take the logs of the powers at each of the mel frequencies.
- Take the discrete cosine transform of the list of mel log powers, as if it were a signal.
- The MFCCs are the amplitudes of the resulting spectrum.

and here's a Matlab toolbox to help you understand it better:

http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/voicebox/voicebox.html